# Wordpress ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I keep getting this error.

I just have my plugin installed on my WP site which calls some .js files with jquery and jquery-ui-core as dependencies.

I call them like so:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
        'vkrwpsprojs',
        plugins_url( '/js/vkrwpsprojs.js', __FILE__ ), 
        array( 'jquery' )
    );

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'fancybox',
        plugins_url( '/js/jquery.fancybox.js', __FILE__ ), 
        array( 'jquery-ui-core' )
    );
```

The head sections of my page ( where the .js files start to get includes ) looks like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=4.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://l/demorwpspro/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://l/demorwpspro/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is the problem that jquery-ui is called before jquery? If so, how to make jquery appear before jquery-ui? The ordering that exists now shoud include jquery first and then jquery-ui, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this useful tutorial](http://matthewruddy.com/using-jquery-with-wordpress/). Also make sure you [include jQuery](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/) the right way. I think that is the problem.